# How to put FreeBSD configuration under Revision Control?

Tags: freebsd, git, configuration-management

I heard once that in Linux it's possible to put whole `/etc/` directory into repository. In fact i already done too much crap on server and I quite disoriented what exactly is setup in there at all.

**Question is how to put FreeBSD all configuration files under Revision Control?**

Is there's any solution for that like packages which helps to automatize this? (The only i know is `etckeeper` which is for Linux)

Comment: Do you just want to put all your config-files under version control? I don't understand what you mean with packages. Version control is unvisersal, yet not automatic. If you change something, you commit the changes so that you can revert later. Or do you mean something entirely else?

Comment: Yeap I mean tracing down configuration changes like `rcs` and `etckeeper` (this one uses git/mercurial) does. I don't speak about `puppet` style stuff

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3750/9454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to track the changes of your own configurations on the same local host, you can happily use RCS.

A wonderful and [easy howto is available on the internet](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialRCSintro.html).

Comment: it's basically tracks files that you know about. with time I even keep forgeting what I did on that server at all. Git style revisioning would be REALLY handy. etckeeper doesn't exists on freebsd =/

Comment: But even GIT doesn't track automatically all the files unless you run a cron job which checks for changes periodically. You still need to check them it. Although I don't know about etckeeper.

Comment: Sure , git doesn't do this by him self, there's few hooks for this. That's why etckeeper appeared. and I basically asking about etckeeper alternative for freebsd.

Comment: So you want changes automatically commited as soon as they have been made?

Comment: in there git basically ignores changes made by system. it's only reacts to changes made by you. + lots's of file permission problems fixed in there.. i just googled out that etckeeper like 20min ago so I don't know much =))

Comment: Sure git ignores all your changes. If you make changes it's up to YOU to commit these changes. There's nothing like automatic commit, unless you brew up a watchdog with `inotify` for instance.

Comment: Finally found it, etckeeper keeps track of owner/permission in additional metadata. git doesn't do this. and all those automaticall system changes like cron is just ignored in there. so I would like to have this package in bsd =)

Comment: Does RCS tracks owner/permissions changes?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the same, and I wish someone would submit patches to etckeeper to support pkg, but an alternative might be to just snapshot the entire filesystem, if your /etc is on zfs.

Comment: Isn't [this support](https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper/commit/1f21fbe26dfbc982492c8b7b90f3758a910f113d) enough?